# What is a monoid in simple terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, monoid, magma

I encountered the term "monoid" but I didn't really understand what is it useful for or what's it about.

If I understand correctly a "monoid" is something defined in the context of a set, an element of the set and a binary operation defined on the specific set.

The binary operation has as left and right operators the same element.

So I think it is something like: $1\cdot1=1\cdot1$ where $\cdot$ is the relevant operation on the set $\mathbb{N}$ .

But what does this mean in layman's terms?

Is this some formal way to define a symmetric operation? Then why is it about one element of the set instead of two? I think $1 + 2 = 2 + 1$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is not a "monoid".

Can someone please help me understand this concept?

Comment: Do you know what a *group* is?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Strictly speaking no, because from my understanding the `group` is defined based on `monoid` so I am stuck there for both

Comment: Monoids can be commutative which is why $\mathbb{N}$ is a monoid. All groups are monoids but not all monoids are groups. The existence of inverses is what differentiates them.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: But these are properties of monoids, I am still not sure what exactly they are as objects or what purpose they serve

Comment: @Jim The definition is what they are. If you find some algebraic system, say $\mathbb{N}$ under addition you would have to prove that it satisfies the properties given in the definition to show that it's a monoid. It's just a set decorated with additional structure. This is a major theme in abstract algebra.

Comment: A monoid is a set with a binary operation that is associative and has an identity element

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: From what I understood, a monoid is a triple $(A, 1, \bigotimes)$, where $A$ is a set, $1$ is an element of $A$ and $\bigotimes$ is a binary operator on $A$ and $1$ is the left and right unit of $\bigotimes$ e.g. the triple $(\mathbb{N}, 1, \cdot)$. So is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @Jim The binary operator must be associative. Other than that you understand it correctly.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Then I still am not clear on why $1\cdot1=1\cdot1$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is a monoid but $1\cdot2=1\cdot2$ is not based on how I specified it

Comment: Saying either of "$1\cdot1=1\cdot1$ is a monoid" or "$1\cdot 2=1\cdot 2$ is not a monoid" makes no sense. An _equation_ is not a set (or an ordered triple).

Comment: Please give some context, e.g. where did you "encounter it"?  Are you familiar with any other algebraic structures such as groups, rings, fields?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I was reading actually about the Knight's tour and there was a mention about group and when starting looking about groups it seems that to understand them I had to understand monoids and there I was stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monoid is a set $M$ together with an associative binary operation $\ast: M\times M\to M$ with an identity element $1_M\in M$; that is to say that for any $a,b,c\in M$, we have:

- **Closure:** $a\ast b\in M$;
- **Associativity:** $$a\ast(b\ast c)=(a\ast b)\ast c;$$
- **Identity:** There exists a $1_M\in M$ such that $1_M\ast a=a\ast 1_M=a$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120685/discussion-on-answer-by-shaun-what-is-a-monoid-in-simple-terms).

Comment: @Shaun: Do you know what the term "monoid" means by the way? Why was it named like that?